# run-length encoding linked list in place (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, run-length-encoding

My LinkedList is singularly linked (Each node has a count + next reference).

I need to create runlengthencode method which takes a LinkedList and returns the run-length encoded version of the list without creating any new nodes - i.e. in place. *It happens to be in Java*.

The problem I am having is keeping track of the nodes representing the start of a run which will appear in the new list as I go along it. Where do I add the rle nodes to in the 
**outer** while loop below?

At present I have a reference called CurrRun and a runner which goes from CurrRun while the values of CurrRun and CurrRun.next are the same.

**Beware: this code has been stripped of its ugly Java syntax wherever possible**

```
//instantiated nodes here

currRun = myListHead.next
Node runner = currRun

while (currRun.next != null){

   int count = 1;

   while (runner.value == runner.next.value){
     count++
     runner = runner.next
   //no more runs in current run
   //update currRun count
   currRun.count = count

   //move currRun to next run node
   currRun = runner.next
   }

}
// return the myHead-> currNode1 -> currNode2 -> .... -> null
return myHead
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

> MOAN: At American Big School they should teach us this but we are left to our own devices

Comment: I'm confused about the in-place restriction.  Run length encoding should generate a list of pairs of (count, value).  This list will likely be a different length than the original list.  How can that be in-place?

Comment: In-place as in no extra memory, i.e. no new Nodes to be created, and no use of additional data structures.

Comment: The solution I came up after some thought, consultation, etc 
has a node which remains with the first node of each runlength series, and the runner.
The runner is one node ahead of the stationary node at all times.
While the runlength condition applies:
increment stationary node count is incremented
Set stationary.next to runner's next.

Once the condition no longer applies the stationary node is moved to the next series, with the 
runner one Node head.
This continues until runner == null.

Answer (score 0):

I would not write the result back into `currRun`.  Instead I would keep a pointer to the nth node in the list and write the nth run back into that node.  That way, your newly rle-encoded list will be contiguous and you don't have to worry about which nodes represent the start of a run and which don't.